# Grace Note wasn't awarded the Constable badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

The SE team quietly introduced [the Constable badge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/274/constable) reserved for [pro-tem modraters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/728/23). On this site, that means Oak, Juan and Grace.

Flashback!

> I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:
>
> [image] [image] [image]

End of flashback. You may remove your sepia glasses now.

Now, the badge's been awarded... [to Juan and Oak.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/274/constable)

Y U NO BADGE GRACE?

Comment: In case you have a memory short circuit like I almost had: Grace's ascension to employeedom happened _after_ the graduation at around the [2nd elections](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/election/2/); the whole point of that round, indeed, was to find mods to replace her. That happened way after the site graduation in ~October 2010.

Comment: TIL badp wasn't a pro-tem moderator

Comment: @Wipqozn * modrater

Answer (score 1):

Employees are excluded in code from getting those badges. I haven't got them for Skeptics.

Comment: Well, I'm glad you've found the reason for the bug :P Can't you just hardcode yourselves in the relevant SQL query or something?

Comment: The problem is, we all look like pro-tem mods on every site, and the same query is used on every site. The same code that excludes me from getting the badge on _every site but_ Webmasters also excludes me from getting it on Webmasters, or it becomes an unmaintainable mess.